# How to fetch an annotation which is have the same co-ordinates from MKClusterAnnotation?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate, mkclusterannotation

I'm currently developing an app where I load different types of annotations by using MKClusterAnnotations from apple's mapkit. We know MKClusterAnotation is `An annotation that groups two or more distinct annotations into a single entity`. Is this possible to fetch or remove annotations from cluster which is have the same co-ordinates?

For Example if there are have 2 clusters with same co-ordinates like `lat: 45.757036789379, long: 4.8989974471952` and another one `lat: 45.757049657763, long: 4.8989858812774`, so when i zoom in or didSelect the Cluster, it should remove from cluster Otherwise It should fetch from cluster member annotations.

Here below Map DidSelect delegate,

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    if let annotation = view.annotation, annotation.isKind(of: MKClusterAnnotation.self) {

        let cluster: MKClusterAnnotation = annotation as! MKClusterAnnotation

        if cluster.memberAnnotations.count > 1 {

            mapView.showAnnotations(cluster.memberAnnotations, animated: true)

            self.isMapDidSelect = true
        } else { //In this case need to fetch memberAnnotations when cluster fails to remove the grouped annotations itself
} } }
```

And Also I have set cluster identifier on view for annotation delegate,

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) {

        let annotationView: CurrentUserAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: CurrentUserAnnotationView.identifier(), for: annotation) as! CurrentUserAnnotationView

        annotationView.selectedMapVisibility = viewModel.selectedMapVisibility.value

        annotationView.photoUrl = viewModel.user.value?.photoUrl

        return annotationView
    }

    if annotation.isKind(of: MKClusterAnnotation.self) {

        if let annotationView: MKAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier) as? ClusterAnnotationView {

            return annotationView
        }
    }

    let annotationView = mapView.annotationViewFor(annotation: annotation)
    annotationView?.clusteringIdentifier = "clusterId"
    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Have you ever seen a cluster with less than two members as your code suggests? Did you try removing the clusteringIdentifier from the members at didSelect?

Comment: I do not understand what you want int this sentence: "it should remove from cluster Otherwise It should fetch from cluster member annotations"

Comment: @Gred Castan Suppose If a different records have same location means when we didSelect that pin or Zoom deep, cluster doesn't decluttered with split into two single annotation pins, it seems still show the grouping with that two records. so in this case I need to fetch that records from **cluster.memberAnnotations** on the line where I checked the statement **cluster.memberAnnotations.count > 1** else case. But that's line should be true cause **memberAnnotations.count had 2 records**.  That's my requirement.

Comment: How can I "Remove the  clusteringIdentifier from the members at didSelect"?  Thank you!